# How to add run arguments within docker test containers

Tags: java, docker, integration-testing, junit5, testcontainers

For the particular image I am trying to run with test containers, it is required to start the container like so after building:

```
docker run \
  -v ~/volume:/tmp/volume\
  --cap-add SYS_NICE --cap-add SYS_RESOURCE --cap-add SYS_PTRACE\
  docker-image
```

However i'm wondering how I go about adding the runtime options `--cap-add SYS_NICE --cap-add SYS_RESOURCE --cap-add SYS_PTRACE` portion to either the Dockerfile and build my own local copy or use the TestContainer methods or would this even be achieved from configuring the docker daemon? I thought Container.withCommand() did this but seems to overwrite the starting command, not adding these run arguments as far as i am aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `GenericContainer#withCreateContainerCmdModifier(...)`, here is the full example:

```java
new GenericContainer<>(
            DOCKER_HOST_CONTAINER_NAME
        ).withCreateContainerCmdModifier(
            it -> it.withHostConfig(
                HostConfig.newHostConfig()
                    .withCapAdd(Capability.NET_ADMIN, Capability.NET_RAW)
                    .withNetworkMode(network.getId())
            )
        ).withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases(dockerHostName)
            .waitingFor(
                Wait.forLogMessage(".*Forwarding ports.*", 1)
            )
```

Comment: what is `network` ?